# Is OAuth a good approach for securing an API of Angular application?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have been going through OAuth2 docs for a couple of days and its really getting confusing.

I have a setup with a spring-boot application configured with OAuth2. I want to write an Angular application to access those APIs. There is a login page in the Angular application. The user will have to enter username and password to login (to get access token). Later in future an Android and iOS App will also be developed to access these APIs. The confusing part is which grant type will be best in this approach?

My findings are resource owner password is the best for this type of client, but where should I keep my client credentials in the Angular application, because it is not safe to put client credentials in the client app and moreover I found it is not possible to register a client in OAuth2 without client secret.

I want to authenticate users from my server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

An answer to your main question (if oAuth is a good approach) is not really appropriate for SO, since it might be too opinion based. For sure it is *an* approach.

But, for your mentioned problem with the client secret, there is a solution.
As you correctly said, there is no way to store the secret in the client that would be safe.
Therefore the *Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange* (or just *Code Flow with PKCE*)  was developed, to authorize a public client without the need to store a static secret in the client.

[image]
(source: [Techworks Blog](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/img/securing-web-applications-with-keycloak/pkce.png))

The key part to mention is, that the application generates a secret at run-time and only uses the Hash of this secret to request a token. Thus, no secret could be caught by the client (Browser, App).
The authorization server, in turn, doesn't pass the access token directly, but only a code to request an access token.
Getting the actual access token is only possible if the secret (that was generated by the application initially) and the code from the authorization server are sent to the server together.
This allows the server to be sure that the request is coming from the application that initially wanted to authenticate, because the server can validate the previously received hash by hashing the received secret again.

As this topic is pretty big, I can only give you some good hints that helped me a lot when I had to deal with this topic:

- [Example with Keycloak for Spring Boot Application + Angular](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2019/08/22/Securing-Web-Applications-With-Keycloak.html)
- [Overview of Code Flows in OIDC](https://christianlydemann.com/creating-an-openid-connect-system-with-angular-8-and-identityserver4-oidc-part-1/)
- [(if desired) Library for using OIDC with Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc)

Comment: Hello Jowey , Thanks for the help. I will go through the links and let you know, but my concern is, the login form returned by the auth server will be prompted, rather I am looking to use the existing login forn in angular client.

Comment: This is right. Though most authorization servers provide the possibilty to either customize the login form (of course this doesn't handle the problem of a redirect and with it the loss of the SPA state - you might have to handle this yourself), or also depending on the authorization server, there might be an API. Over the API it might be possible to use your own login form and follow the Code Flow. But keep in mind that if you use the API, you might have to implement this again in the next application you might develop, instead of just using your existing login (with custom design).